# What to do if a team member does not work but they have to answer committee questions?

Tags: masters, projects, france

I am a master student in a French university and the university states that for a project students must form a team. However, I ended up doing the whole work by myself (They always come up with an excuse to avoid working). We have to present the project in a **French**, the committee will ask us questions.

My French level is at best A2 on CEFR. I am afraid that when they ask questions I won't be able to answer them due to my language skills also my colleagues probably would not be able to answer since they have not done any work which would result in a poor grading of our project.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, the committee members are able to distinguish between difficulties which are due to language issues and incompetence. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification if you don't understand a question and maybe you have a chance to make som drawings on paper or on a board / flip-chart which show the relevant concepts.